# AWS Lambda using a windows DLL

Tags: dll, aws-lambda

I am trying to use AWS Lambda to convert incoming files to S3 buckets. For the conversion I would have to rely upon a third party DLL written in C++ with windows dependencies.

Could you give me a hint how a windows DLL could be used under AWS Lambda's execution environment?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Lambda runs on Linux VMs based on Amazon [Linux AMIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) so no, you can't use a windows DLL. Have a look at [Azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-overview) which run in Windows containers.